# HP Pavillion laptop won't start up at all

Tags: hp-pavilion

I last used my HP laptop a month ago. Today I plugged it in and as soon as I pushed the power button it comes on for 1 second and then shuts off. The power adaptor is fine and providing power.

Answer (score 1):

Another problem that could exist, might be that the BIOS has become corrupted. Do the caps lock and num lock lights flash. If so, count the number of flashes before pausing. Then search HP's website for flash/beep codes. This can also help you to determine if the problem exists somewhere else in the PC, such as the hard drive or RAM. However if it is indeed the BIOS, this too can be fixed using a USB floppy disk drive and a floppy with the BIOS recovery software, which is relatively easy to find.

If your laptop does not have these flashing lights or beeps, the problem could be in the battery and/or power supply. Try taking the battery off and plug in the power supply, then power it on. If the problem persists, it is likely the power supply. If not... the battery is probably shorted.

Answer (score 0):

My wife's laptop had the same issue recently.  Open it up, find each and every connection in there (cables, RAM, cards, etc.) pull it out, and put it straight back in.  Because computers regularly heat and cool, the plugs can work themselves loose.  Leaving the computer in direct sunlight could cause the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the power cord and battery so the computer is completely disconnected from power (except for the BIOS battery), then hold the power button down for a couple minutes and reconnect everything and see if it works then.